# Where are the maps I downloaded for Call of Duty: Black Ops 2?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I downloaded the Uprising and Apocalypse map packs for Black Ops 2 but once they were done installing I could not find the maps. Where are they?

I am using a PS3 if that helps.

Comment: I tried to download it again but it did not help and when I go to the store in game (multiplayer) the only things I is Nuketown and Nuketown Zombies.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?